# Bootstrap Modal changing the Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my web application, there is a picture of a person. When you click on it, it opens a Modal (I use Bootstrap for this) and show information about that person. **Important here** is that the URL changed!

Example:

you open the picture and the URL is:

`domain.com/persons#name=FirstnameLastname&referrer=website`

this is when a normal person click the picture, but I need also a URL like this:
`domain.com/persons#name=FirstnameLastname&referrer=email`

this URL shows more information from the person, that the other URL doesn't show.

**My Code:**

```html
{{#each employees}}
          <div class="pb40 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 visible-lg visible-sm visible-md">
            <a href="#name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website" data-toggle="modal">
              <img src="/aboutus/employee/{{_id}}/teaser_image" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
            </a>
          </div>

<!-- information -->

{{/each}}
```

and call the modal with this:

```html
{{#each employees}}
    {{!--Modal--}}
    <div id="name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Information ... -->
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

When I run it, and click on a picture (The picture comes from the database), they only change the URL, but don't open the Modal with the URL

Any ideas for what's going wrong?

Comment: When you added data-toggle in a element, add data-target: your id too

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the target id, try if it works, just add data-traget:

```html
<a href="#name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website">
              <img src="/aboutus/employee/{{_id}}/teaser_image" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to use data-target

```
{{#each employees}}
      <div class="pb40 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 visible-lg visible-sm visible-md">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website">
          <img src="/aboutus/employee/{{_id}}/teaser_image" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
        </a>
      </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When i do this what you say, it means:

```html
{{#each employees}}

<div class="pb40 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 visible-lg visible-sm visible-md">
            <a href="#name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website">
              <img src="/aboutus/employee/{{_id}}/teaser_image" class="img-responsive img-circle"/>
            </a>
</div>

{{/each}}
```

and this is the call:

```html
<div id="name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        {{!--Modal content--}}
```

nothing change. but when i do this:

```html
{{#each employees}}

<div class="pb40 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 visible-lg visible-sm visible-md">
              <a href="#name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{firstname}}{{lastname}}" onclick="window.location.hash = 'name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}&referrer=website';">
              <img src="/aboutus/employee/{{_id}}/teaser_image" class="img-responsive img-circle"/>
            </a>
</div>

{{/each}}
```

call it with this:

```html
<div id="name={{firstname}}{{lastname}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        {{!--Modal content--}}
```

then they open the Modal, and change the URL. I dont know whats the problem here is, but it sucks so much. Now It works but not really right.

I believe i become now problems, when i want to change the Content of the modals when it is referrer=website and referrer=email

i dont know how can i do this, because i use URL.js from Websanova and can read every thing of the URL, but here it is differcult, because they open this modal, what i give him in the data-target. 
do i think i need, two modals, with different ID one with {{firstname}}{{lastname}}email and one with {{firstname}}{{lastname}}website.

but how can i say now, hay change the data-target when it is website and when it is email.

I really hope that you can understand, what i want, because this job makes me crazy ...
thank you for help